# Facebook WordPress plugin cannot submit Opengraph Action

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-opengraph

I went through the step by step provided by Facebook here: https://developers.facebook.com/wordpress/

If you scroll down to: Enable Publishing to an Author's Timeline
This is the step I am on and what seem to be an issue.
Here is my problem:
 **"In order for posts to authors' Timelines to be public, You will need to submit your newly created Open Graph action for approval before posts to authors' Timelines will appear to the public."**
When I press the submit link next to my action I get this error:

```
Publish Actions
You must publish at least one action to your Timeline using this action type. Review the documentation.
```

So How can I submit it if I cannot submit it from my blog until it is approved? 
When I do a test blog in wordpress nothing posts to Facebook.

Comment: You should take a look at the plugin support site for this. http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/facebook

Answer (score 0):

You'll just have to publish a few actions with a user-account that is either registered as "Developer" or "Tester" for the app. You can check if the actions have been published successfully by looking at the Activity Log of your test-users. After you've published a few actions, you can submit the action.

However: make sure to test your app with the Auth-Test-Users from your App-Dashboard - that's the way how Facebook will test your app for approval, so if your app fails here - bad luck!

Comment: Michael Where Do I publish the actions and how? I created a blog post in wordpress and the action did not seem to kick off. Do I do this from Facebook or from wordpress?

Comment: That seems to be the problem. Where can I publish. Since I did not wrote any code and I am using the Facebook Plugin for WordPress that Facebook provided I am a bit lost.

Comment: The Action should be automatically published every time you publish a new post in wordpress!

Also make sure to check:

/wp-admin/admin.php?page=facebook-social-publisher
/wp-admin/admin.php?page=facebook-debug